# Check to see if UITextField has a numeric value greater than 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` and I only want a number greater than 0 ( I don't want non-numeric characters or the value 0 )

This is how I check to see if it is empty:

```
if(seizure.text.length==0)
```

This is how I check to see if it is equal to 0:

```
else if(seizure.text doubleValue]==0)
```

How can I check for non-numeric characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSScanner`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html) will do the job nicely here. Unlike `-[NSString doubleValue]`, its `scanDouble:` can parse and then also tell you whether it consumed the entire string, so you will know that there are non-numerical characters present.

Demonstration on some test cases. See the comments for descriptions of the expected results.

```
NSArray * texts = @[// First four unacceptable because non-numeric
                    @"", @"Hello, world!", @"1.0 excelsior", @"Jiminy 1.0 Crickets",
                    // These three unacceptable because 0 or less
                    @"0.0" @"0", @"-2048",
                    // Last three are good
                    @"3.14159", @"1", @"10000000000.0"];
for( NSString * text in texts ){
    NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:text];
    double val;
    [scanner scanDouble:&val];
    // Scanned the whole string and ended up with a positive value
    if( [scanner isAtEnd] && val > 0 ){
        NSLog(@"'%@'? I accept.", text);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"'%@' is no good.", text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! It works but the @"" and @" " seems not works . So it's necessary to add text.length > 0. 
I deduce [scanner scanDouble:&val] and [scanner isAtEnd] look if text is a number ?
Because if I want only number (even negative) and I do -> if( ([scanner isAtEnd]) && (seizure.text.length > 0)) , it works perfectly .

Comment: This procedure rejects `@""` (empty string) and a string that consists only of whitespace because they're not numeric, and you said you didn't want negative numbers. I can modify this if it's not quite right.

Comment: I did it myself. Thanks you Josh :-)

Answer (score 3):

First check to see if you have any characters in the string, then check to make sure that it only contains numeric characters, and finally check to see if the value is greater than 0:

```
if (seizure.text.length > 0)
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumbers = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    if ([seizure.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumbers].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        if ([seizure.text doubleValue] > 0)
        {
            // Text Field contains a numeric value greater than 0
            NSLog(@"Good number.");
            return;
        }
    }
}

// If we make it to here, it does not meet your requirements.
NSLog(@"Bad Number.");
```

Answer (score 1):

`[seizure.text doubleValue] == 0` will be true either if `seizure.text` is a textual representation of zero *or* if it doesn't contain a valid textual representation of a number (see the documentation for `doubleValue`).

In other words if this expression is false then you have a string value which starts with a number. However you still don't know if you string value contains only a number, e.g. `[@"2.5 miles" doubleValue]` has the value `2.5`. If you need to handle strings like this you should look at `NSScanner`.